# How to convert the String to a ampscript code in email?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, content-builder

I am storing the email content in the google sheet and then importing it into the data extension. The email is dynamic & is fetching data from the data extension.

For one of the fields i,E **URL** , I am storing the text value in data extension as follows -
concat(‘www.abcd.com/’,@path)

Within the email, the code looks like below,

**Issue** :

```
Set @url = ArributeValue(“URL”) ==> set @url = “concat(‘www.abcd.com/’,@path)”
```

**What I want** :

```
Set @url = ArributeValue(“URL”) ==> set @url = concat(‘www.abcd.com/’,@path)
```

The issue now is that in the @url variable string value is stored and instead of string value I want the string value to be treated as a code.

I tried treatascontent() but it dint work. Is there a way to get what I am trying to do above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to set it as inline ampscript or as an ampscript block for it to render so something like `%%=concat(‘www.abcd.com/’,@path)=%%` in the DE or

```
Set @url = Treatascontent(Concat('%','%=',AttributeValue("URL"), '=%','%'))
```

Should do it.